# Is anyone using PureComponents controls with success?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

We are looking into the PureComponents Ultimate Suite for a WinForms project.  The controls seem to offer a lot of nice function but we are concerned about their stability.  Does anyone have experience with these controls?

http://www.purecomponents.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the  Krypton Suite 4.1.1 from https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

There is a free toolkit that contains many of the controls. The tools included in the suite add a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using them; they haven't given any problems with stability, but I'm concerned that I haven't actually been able to get in contact with the developer.  But without problems, there hasn't been a real need.

**UPDATED:** I wanted to update that they seem to be out of business.  At the end, they were offering source to the components, so I was able to get the source, which was a very nice thing.  But their URL no longer resolves.

Comment: I know it's been 10 years but maybe you're still here. I have decompiled the NicePanel and turned it into a .NET6 component.  Do you happen to still have the source code to any of the components? I'd rather play with the actual source code than decompiled code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that source any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I ordered and downloaded PureComponents a week ago, to see how they stack up against other control suites I have, such as Krypton, SyncFusion, and TeleRik RAD. The PureComponents components never were visible in the toolbox and were not listed in the "Choose ToolBox Items" dialog box. I emailed their tech support seven times before deciding to dump it. And now it seems they are out of business. Good riddance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it... the look is very nice, but I have a lot of troubles.

The VS IDE become very slow when you add their controls, often it locks your project on the form you are editing (you have to exit from VS to be able to edit another form...)

As well, after adding a few controls I get a message "out of memory" when trying to compile.

Moving or resizing controls is also sometimes a little bit tricky. Sometimes the controls seems to do what they want, you are unable to size them as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been trying out the PureComponents Winforms Ultimate 2010 Suite.

My findings are that superficially they look extrmemely attractive and offer a good range of options but in use they have proved to be little short of a disaster from the developer's point of view. My applications are typically based around a series of inherited forms and there appears to have been little or no testing done on this scenario. A common problem is that after running a debug session a design window containing these control crashes or hangs and needs to be closed and reloaded. This gets pretty irritating after a while! This happens on both VS2008 and VS2010.

I have also experienced a number of application crashes with no apparent cause while testing. If you step through the application code the crash doesn't happen and this is frankly unacceptable.

I wanted to like these controls as I have been using their original NicePanel for years without problems and was expecting something better.

I am now in the process of removing the PureComponents controls and replacing them with my tried and trusted alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it and even though it's a bit buggy, I have figured out some work arounds and like the way the controls look.

For example, if you sometimes try to copy and paste controls they won't paste because paste has been disable for some strange reason. I do a cut with ctrl-x then do a ctrl-z to get it back and move the control back to where it was before. Now that I have the control in the clipboard I can past it as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using PureComponents since 2008.  I love the way they look and used them in many apps.  Support used to be good but now, like others have mentioned, zero response to emails.  Before trying to contact them I went ahead and bought 2010 for $19 then it sat there for a year and here I am now trying to use it to upgrade an existing application.  So using something else is not an option.  The entire app is basically based around the colorlist control.

However, now that I'm using VS 2010 these components will not license at all!

It was never an issue before:

```
Public Sub New()

    PureComponents.EntrySet.Licensing.RunTimeLicenseKey = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx........."

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

This just does not work at all.  That dang trial popup comes up on the production machines.  Dev machine is fine.

Everyone gets the source with purchase.  Has anyone looked to see if all this nonsense can be diverted?

Comment: I figured out my issue.  It would seem they changed the way their licensing registers itself or rather WHEN.  Because I was publicly creating an instance of a component outside the forms class, that was firing before the runtimelicensekey function.

The solution to this was to simply remove the creation of the control from the form and put it in a global module.

It registers fine now.